# How to pass lists as multiple arguments in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function that accepts lists a, b as its inputs; outputs a list.

```
sigm = function(x,a,b){
return(exp(a*x+b))
}
```

What I am trying to do is the function should take a value from a, say a[i], and take another value from b, say b[j]. Ideally, I want the total dim of the output to be dim(a)*dim(b)*dim(x)

I tried using mapply but could not get around.

```
 mapply(sigm, 1:4,1:4, 4:1)  
 [1] 1.484132e+02 1.096633e+03 5.987414e+04 2.415495e+07
```

It still gives me just list of length 4. I am trying to get a list of 64.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example ?

Comment: Please review [mcve]

Comment: You probably want `outer`.

Comment: in your example you say you want 64 values, that would be `dim(a)*dim(b)*dim(x)`, not `dim(a)*dim(b)`. I took this assumption for my answer below, maybe you could clarify ?

Answer (score 0):

first build a data.frame that contains all the values you want to combine :

```
df <- setNames(expand.grid(x,a,b),c("x","a","b"))
```

then you can use `mapply`:

```
mapply(sigm, df$x,df$a,df$b)
```